# Cakephp Save Multiple Data in Multiple Rows

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I used multiple Select Drop down which contains ids. I want to store that ids in one table as new records.There are many Elements in my form but this drop down is stored seperately.
select options Array is `$array['D']['d_id']`; which is

```
array(
  ['d_id'] = array(
    [0] = 1,
    [1] = 2,
    [2] = 3,
    [3] = 4
  )
);
```

and the e_id is current user id from Session. which is `$eid = 1`;
I want to insert like following

**table_1**

```
|---------------------|
|id(AI) | e_id | d_id |
|---------------------| 
|  1    |  1   |  1   | 
|---------------------|     
|  2    |  1   |  2   |
|---------------------|     
|  3    |  1   |  3   |
|---------------------|     
|  4    |  1   |  4   | 
|---------------------|
```

what should I use? I used save, saveAll, saveMany and also assigned values
 
like

```
$this->D->d_id = $this->data['D']['d_id'];
$this->D->e_id = $this->data['D']['d_id'];
$this->D->saveMany(); ||$this->D->saveAll();||$this->D->save();
```

Comment: thank you [u2460470](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2460470/u2460470) for Editing my question properly. It's my first question on StackOverflow.

Comment: May be following post can help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396708/cakephp-save-multiple-rows

Comment: What were your problem when you use save, saveAll, saveMany? and what version of cakePHP are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.1.5. when I was simple save()  and savaAll() no data were inserted in db. But when I used saveMany() it worked. saveMany basically is made to insert multiple rows in table. when you have list of data displayed and want to save each list index as seperate record saveMany() is useful. I also used it and solved my problem/